# Jacoco with Android Gradle 1.3.0

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

With gradle 1.2.3 and android studio, running `./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport` gives me a coverage report based on my project's tests.

Switching to gradle 1.3.0 causes this task to fail, giving me `Task 'createDebugCoverageReport' not found in root project '[edited]'`. Looking at gradle's source code, the jacoco part has been removed in 1.3.0 [1.2.3 source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/03842a2bd83ffcee6c1b8649ae6dbe038e29bf2c/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/coverage/JacocoExtension.groovy), [1.3.0 source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_1.3.0/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle)

I can't find any discussion on why was it removed and/or how can I run this coverage report using gradle 1.3.0. Any ideas?

Comment: Gradle 1.3? The current version of Gradle is 2.6. Do you mean the android plugin?

Comment: I'm referring to Gradle plugin for Android Studio: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/1.2.3 . I'll make it clearer in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was re-enabled in gradle 1.3.1 ([Release Notes](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)), switching to that gradle version works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Could you drop down the list at the right panel of Android Studio(Gradle mark) ?
There is "Tasks" -> "other", and you can find

> create{$flavorName}DebugCoverageReport

and then do
./gradlew create{$flavorName}DebugCoverageReport

for example
./gradlew createBananaDebugCoverageReport

Comment: Thanks, but this was a 1.3.0-specific bug, in 1.3.1 works again.

Comment: I had the same issue in 1.5.0 so I think this answer should be considered helpful.